# Substitute of Date.parse("March 21, 2012")

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on [angular timer](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/) and I stuck at a point. I need to parse a date in my  controller. In javascript, I can achieve the same by doing

```
var d = Date.parse("March 21, 2012"); //1332268200000
```

Is there any way I can do it in `angularjs`. So far I've tried.

```
$scope.endTime = $filter('date')($scope.defaultProduct.end_date, 'm d, Y')
Date.parse($scope.endTime); // Not working
```

Here is directive code.

```
<timer end-time="1451628000000">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer>
```

How could I pass date in `end-time` attribute ?

Comment: *"In javascript, I can achieve the same by doing"* Not reliably you can't. That string is not in the only format that [the specifcation defines](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). It might work on some browsers, in some locales; and not others, or other locales.

Comment: Why, I saw some tutorials out there. Is there anything I'm missing ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. Will you please suggest me angular way of doing that ?

Comment: You can check this site for some help:
<http://dnasir.github.io/angular-dateParser/demo.html>

Comment: Try to format as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, it s the "basic" format for Date.parse. You can omit the hour if you want.

Comment: Sorry, it had a char at the end: http://dnasir.github.io/angular-dateParser/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to use the $filter for date provided by angular.js itself.

In HTML Template Binding:
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}

In JavaScript:
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)

For example : formattedDate = $filter('date')(dateObj, "yyyy-MM-dd");

Please have a look at the following link for more information : 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: True but It will only give me a formated date. I need parsed date. Like see the timer directive from `angular-timer` i.e. `<timer end-time="1451628000000">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer>`. How could I pass the value in `end-time` attribute ?